# Jersey Client supported with Android?

Tags: java, android, rest, maven, jersey-client

I want to use REST Jersey Client to invoke web services.  But it is failing when invoked from android app; the same web service call works when invoked from simple java client (without any Android code).  Does it mean Jersey Client doesn't work when invoked in Android's context or it needs any specific configuration to make a REST call?

My pom.xml has this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.13</version>
</dependency>
```

My sample code:

```
  Response getResponse = ClientBuilder.newClient()
              .target("http://myserver:8081").path("/users/employees")
              .request()
              .get();
```

I see these ERRORS in android emulator logs:

```
Failed resolving Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/OsgiRegistry; interface 2690 'Lorg/osgi/framework/SynchronousBundleListener;'
Link of class 'Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/OsgiRegistry;' failed
VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/OsgiRegistry;)
...
Cannot find default implementation of the HK2 ServiceLocatorGenerator
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider of org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered.
```

Related comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6187125/1888822):
"Android has Dalvik Virtual Machine, not original JVM. I think this the reason why Jersey Client API does not work in Android OS. but I'am nog sure!"

Comment: Another pointer : [Jersey 2.x Client on Android](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/jersey_2_x_client_on) ... problems still there

Answer (score 0):

This post is related:

[When using Jersey for restful api in Android app I get this error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680035/when-using-jersey-for-restful-api-in-android-app-i-get-this-error/)

It seems that the Jersey Client is not supported in android: I tried importing a working jersey Client for REST api program in android and got a fatal exception.

```
12-16 16:41:33.049    3711-3711/com.program.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.program.example, PID: 3711
java.lang.VerifyError: com/sun/jersey/core/impl/provider/entity/MimeMultipartProvider
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:508)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:174)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:160)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:342)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:118)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:191)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:187)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:187)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:159)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:669)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I wish I could make it a comment...